# Consider the universe $U=\{x | x \in \mathbb{Z}, 1 \le x \le 10\}$ and the following subsets of $U$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A = \{ 2,5,9 \}$

$B = \{ 1,4,7,8,10 \}$

$C = \{ 1,2 \}$

In the following questions we denote $A′$ the complement of $A$. i.e. $A' = U - A$

1. $A′$
2. $A \cup B \cup C$
3. $B′  −  A$
4. $A  \bigtriangleup  B$

I can't access my notes and finding this hard to work out. Thanks.

Comment: The questions 1-4. Yes I've been trying for ages to solve but all the notation etc is very new to me.

Comment: Hint: What are the graphical representations of the different operations, eg. what is the graphical representation of the complement of a set in terms of a Venn diagram (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram)?

Answer (score 5):

1. $A' = U - A.$
2. $A \cup B \cup C = \{x\lvert\, x\in A \lor x\in B \lor x\in C\}.$
3. $B' - A = (U-B)-A.$
4. $A\Delta B = \{x\lvert\,(x\in A \lor x\in B)\land x\notin (A \cap B)\}=\{x\lvert\, x\in (A\cup B) \land x \notin (A\cap B)\}.$

I will do 1, you can probably do the rest from here.

$U=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$. So $A'=U-A=U -\{2,5,9\}=\{1,3,4,6,7,8,10\}.$

Here are the Venn diagrams of the sets:

(1) is not A, (2) is A or B or C, (3) is not B minus A, (4) is A iff not B.

[image]

Comment: Got it. The last question 4 though, could you help with that. Thanks.

Comment: @Liam What's elements are in A but not in B and what elements are in B but not in A? That's $A\Delta B$. Cheers.